# Powershell - Setting a variable inside a function not setting it globally?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$firstRun = 'True'

$file | ForEach-Object {

    Function Do-Stuff {
        if ($firstRun = 'True') {

            write-host "null"
            $firstRun = 'False'
        }
    }
Do-Stuff
}
```

When I call Function 'Do-Stuff', it will run the first time, no matter where I place **$firstRun = 'False'**, it returns true and intiates the if block again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check out the docs on `variable scope`. i suspect that is where your glitch is occurring ...

Comment: kool! [*grin*] it looks like your problem is related to scope. ///// purely as an aside ... i would replace all your tests for the string `true` with tests for the _boolean_ `$True`. it makes no difference in your code, but fits better with how PoSh handles False/True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$firstRun = 'True'` is setting `$firstRun` to the String `'True'`. If you want to see if it equals that value the comparison operator is `-eq`, so `$firstRun -eq 'True'`

For more information on comparison operators run `Get-Help about_comparison_operators`

---

Thanks for letting us know about the typo, I'll stick with your example to show how you can prefix your variables with `global:` so you get the required variable scope.

```
$firstRun = 'True'
Function Do-Stuff {
    if ($global:firstRun  -eq 'True') {

        Write-Host "True"
        $global:firstRun  = 'False'
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "False"
    }
}

$file | ForEach-Object { Do-Stuff }
```

For more information on scopes check `Get-Help about_scopes`.

Comment: Shoot, that actually a typo in my sample code. Its not like that in my actual code....

Comment: Adding $global:fixed the issue I was having

Answer (score 2):

Use `$global:firstRun` instead of the `$firstRun` inside the function to reference variable in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return something.

Here is an example with a returning value.

```
$value1 = 3
$value2 = 5
function Calculate-Something ($number1,$number2)
{
   $result = $number1 + $number2
   return $result
}
$value3 = Calculate-Something -number1 $value1 -number2 $value2
Write-Host $value3
```

This code sample would add up value1 and value2 and would write the result:

```
8
```